What kind of PHP syntax is this?
Can you please tell me what kind of PHP syntax is:
echo Html::{'div.my-class#my-id'}('This is element content')

?
It's from https://github.com/decodelabs/tagged library.
I mean I know what it does, but I don't understand the syntax used and why it works :) (braces immediately after the scope operator). Looks like they're using braces to 'generate' the name of the function to call, but - on the other hand - it contains characters like '.' and '#" and variable parameters ('my-class', 'my-id'). I'm confused...
I tried googling for over 2 hours, but no luck :/

I think this is what the developers refer to as a "static frontage" and "content transformation". There is more information about this here. The code inside the curly braces would normally be resolved to a variable, but the static frontage may resolve 'div.my-class#my-id' to a dynamic function or macro and, at that point, the fact that you have brackets at the end makes sense. This technique is employed by some other PHP libraries to provide polyfills to back-port new functions to old versions or to provide a parser on top of the language.

The starting point seems to be the __callStatic() method, which then sends all of the arguments to a conversion method.

My thinking is the HTML class is dynamically invoking a method which outputs html, like this <div class="my-class" id="my-id">This is element content</div>
I use a method like this in a class that dynamically calls a method in the same class and passes attributes: return $this->{$methodName}($attributes);

Yes, that sounds right. Based on what @allan.simon suggested and the example code I posted, you could implement a very basic version of this using __callStatic() and a related function such as call_user_func_array(). Without looking at the code, it would seem sensible to have some kind of DOM that you can use to build the HTML code. XML would be an obvious candidate for this.

Topically relevant: PHP __callStatic & invalid method name characters and What are the valid characters in PHP variable, method, class, etc names? and How do I access this object property with an illegal name? and Exotic names for methods, constants, variables and fields - Bug or Feature? and PHP variable / function / class names using special characters

and What does PHP operator ->{...} mean? and PHP static properties in double quotes and Call method by string? and How to call a function from a string stored in a variable? and Why am I not able to use a number in php public function class at starting?

let's reconstruct this from first principle

you can use {value} to put a dynamic method/attribute name

i.e if you have
class Dog {
    public string $name = 'doggy';
    public function walk() {
    }
}

you can do
$dog = new Dog();
$dog->walk(); 
$dog->{'walk'}(); // equivalent 

echo $dog->name;
echo $dog->{'name'};

as you can do this and 'walk' and name are value, they can also come from variables
$attribute = 'name';
$dog->{$attribute};


PHP has some magic methods to treat undefined method / attributes , the full list is there https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

for example __callStatic() will be called whenever you call a static method for which the name is undefined
like this
class Html
{
    static public function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        // Note: value of $name is case sensitive.
        echo "Calling object method '$name' "
             . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";
    }
    
};

Html::iDontExist();

will output Calling object method 'iDontExist' 

now if we mix both 1 and 2 we can do

Html::{"Hello world"};

It will output Calling object method 'Hello World' 
Conclusion

using {} syntax you can have method that don't follow normal convention (i.e they can have spaces, emoji, special caracters etc. )
using overloading magic method like __callStatic you can have methods that don't exists before hand

so by combining 1 and 2 your library is allowing a method to already be an argument by itself and all the logic of treating this name will be in a __callSatic
so it would be the same as doing Html::something('div.my-class#my-id', 'This is element content' )  if something was a defined static method

The missing piece was the __callStatic function - now it's all clear how it works. Thanks a lot!

I think there's a class named HTML which is calling a static method dynamically to output some HTML.
In the example below, I'm dynamically calling a method which, in a simple way, does the same thing. I'm also passing an argument to generate additional text.
<?php

class myClass {

    protected function foo($string) {
        echo 'foo says: ' . $string;
    }
    
    protected function bar($string) {
        echo 'bar says: ' . $string;
    }

    public function hello($method, $string)
    {
        return $this->{$method}($string);
    }

    // static methods
    protected static function baz($string) {
        echo 'baz says: ' . $string;
    }
    
    public static function staticHello($method, $string)
    {
        return self::{$method}($string);
    }

}

$class = new MyClass;

// dynamically call the `foo` method and pass a string
$class->hello('foo', 'this is my foo string');

// outputs
// foo says: this is my foo string.

$class->hello('bar', 'this is my bar string');

// outputs
// bar says: this is my bar string.

// static
$class::staticHello('baz', 'this is my baz string');

// outputs
// baz says: this is my baz string


Your functionality is slightly different to the OP's example, because is no expectation of there being a method called div.my-class#my-id existing, so an overloading method such as __callStatic() has to be used to capture the exception that would normally be generated for a missing function. If you look at the example, there isn't actually any function called as such, the {'div.my-class#my-id'} is acting as a placeholder for the function name. The equivalent code would be Html::div.my-class#my-id('This is element content') which is of course invalid.

@NoelWhitemore valid critique, however I do think it answers OP's question about braces after the scope resolution operator. Unless I misread, which is alway an option lol.

No, your answer is valid. I just thought it might be helpful to point out the distinction in case it wasn't obvious to others. I've always used overloading functions in my own code to some extent, but the OP's example looked weird on first sight. Possibly a bit too clever for its own good, or at least too clever for me :) Call me simple but echo '<div class="my-class" id="my-id">This is element content</div>'; still works for me (actually, I use templates now, but that's besides the point).

Actually I knew (or at least expected) that the part in braces stands for the function name (or, as I put it - to 'generate' the name). But I didn't know how come 'div.my-class#my-id' resolves to a valid function name. __callStatic was the missing piece :)

The example given is possible thanks to the __callStatic magic method. This exploits a unique feature in PHP that allows the user to make a call to an undefined method without PHP generating a fatal error, similar to how a user-defined exception handler works. This approach allows the developer to route all actions through a common interface without having to define separate methods for each action in advance, and helps to streamline the interface for users when they write their code so that instead of having to do something like
$html = new HTML();
$div = $html->createDiv('my-id', 'my-class');
$div->setHTML('This is element content');
echo $div->getHTML();

they can do this instead
echo Html::{'div.my-class#my-id'}('This is element content')

without the need to instantiate any classes or use intermediate variables to store things. My strawman example is deliberately verbose but demonstrates why a developer might need to simplify the interface to this sort of functionality.
The following code shows a working example of how __callStatic can be used:
class weird_php_magic
{
    public static function __callStatic
    (
        string $method,
        array $args
    ): string|Stringable|null {
        // ...$args allows any number of arguments to be sent to the function
        return static::convert($method, ...$args);
    }
    
    public static function convert
    (
        string $name,
        mixed $content,
        ?array $options = [],
        ?callable $setup = null
    ): string|Stringable|null {
        // parse $name in some way to determine the function you want to call
        
        // $content contains the arguments that can be sent to that function
        
        // ...or just dump $name and $content to see if it worked or not
        var_dump($name);
        var_dump($content);
        
        return null;
    }
}

weird_php_magic::{'this does not exist'}('nor this');

OUTPUT
string(19) "this does not exist"
string(8) "nor this"

I tested this code with PHP 8.2. Once the convert() function has something equivalent to a function name and the arguments for that function, it should then be fairly straightforward to parse the details using a regex and work out what the user needs to do.
